# Asyncio Run Loop Errors in Python 3.7

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I am trying to use the asyncio packages to execute concurrent calls from one SQL Server to another in order to extract data.  I'm hitting an issue of at the portion of `myLoop.run_until_complete(cors)` where it is telling me that the event loop is already running.  I will admit that I am new to this package and may be overlooking something simple.

```
import pyodbc
import sqlalchemy
import pandas
import asyncio
import time

async def getEngine(startString):

    sourceList = str.split(startString,'=')
    server = str.split(sourceList[1],';')[0]    
    database = str.split(sourceList[2],';')[0]
    user = str.split(sourceList[3],';')[0]
    password = str.split(sourceList[4],';')[0]

    returnEngine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://"+user+":"+password+"@"+server+"/"+database+"?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0")

    return returnEngine


async def getConnString(startString):

    sourceList = str.split(startString,'=')
    server = str.split(sourceList[1],';')[0]
    database = str.split(sourceList[2],';')[0]
    user = str.split(sourceList[3],';')[0]
    password = str.split(sourceList[4],';')[0]

    return "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server="+server+";Database="+database+";Uid="+user+";Pwd="+password+";"



async def executePackage(source,destination,query,sourceTable,destTable,lastmodifiedDate,basedOnStation):

     sourceConnString = getConnString(source)
     destEngine = getEngine(destination)
     sourceConn = pyodbc.connect(sourceConnString)

     newQuery = str.replace(query,'dateTest',str(lastmodifiedDate))
     df = pandas.read_sql(newQuery,sourceConn)

     print('Started '+sourceTable+'->'+destTable)
     tic = time.perf_counter()
     await df.to_sql(destTable,destEngine,index=False,if_exists="append")
     toc = time.perf_counter()
     secondsToFinish = toc - tic
     print('Finished '+sourceTable+'->'+destTable+' in '+ str(secondsToFinish) +' seconds')


async def main():

    connString = "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=myServer;Trusted_Connection=yes;"
    myConn = pyodbc.connect(connString)

    cursor = myConn.cursor()
    df = pandas.read_sql('exec mySql_stored_proc',myConn)    

    if len(df.index) > 0:
        tasks = [executePackage(df.iloc[i,10],df.iloc[i,11],df.iloc[i,7],df.iloc[i,8],df.iloc[i,9],df.iloc[i,5],df.iloc[i,17])for i in range(len(df))]

    myLoop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    cors = asyncio.wait(tasks)
    myLoop.run_until_complete(cors)

if __name__ =="__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: You don't need `run_until_complete` because you are already in an `async def`. Just replace the last three lines of `main` with `await asyncio.wait(tasks)`. Note, however, that `DataFrame.to_sql` is not async, so awaiting it will probably not have the desired effect.

Comment: Awesome thanks!  Got me past that error, now just on to learning all the other stuff ;)